# What does qnh attribute stands for in hector_uav_msgs/Altimeter?

Tags: hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to use `hector_uav_msgs/Altimeter` for barometer sensor data publishing, but I cant figure out what does `qnh` attribute stand for? Is it possible it's pressure difference?

I understand this is a RTFM-like question, but I can't find any documentation regarding this stack. Any links to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154456/what-does-qnh-attribute-stands-for-in-hector_uav_msgs/altimeter?/) by [rock-ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/6716/rock-ass/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2014-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It stands for [barometric pressure adjusted to sea level as described on Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/QNH).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0